# How to Install Electrum in Lubuntu 18.04 on 32 bit PC

Tags: lubuntu, 32-bit

I have recently installed Lubuntu 18.04 on my 32-bit PC.

I have spent the past two days trying various suggested methods to install Electrum wallet. Unfortunately it appears that all the methods that I have tried are for 64-bit PC's.

How do I install an Electrum wallet on my 32-bit Lubuntu 18.04 PC?

Edit:

Electrum wallet is a program for storing and managing bitcoin cryptocurrency addresses. Details can be found at https://electrum.org/#home

Here is a link to one of the Electrum wallet installation guides that I tried. Part of this link specifically covers Lubunty 18.04:
https://www.shareannonce.com/david/tutorial/2d4

In terminal I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools python3-pyqt5 python3-pip
wget https://download.electrum.org/3.3.5/Electrum-3.3.5.tar.gz
tar xvf Electrum-3.3.5.tar.gz
```

All appeared to work well. I then tried to launch Electrum and got the following:

```
python3 ~/Electrum-3.3.5/run_electrum
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/richard/Electrum-3.3.5/run_electrum", line 355, in <module>
    fd, server = daemon.get_fd_or_server(config)
  File "/home/richard/Electrum-3.3.5/electrum/daemon.py", line 77, in get_fd_or_server
    remove_lockfile(lockfile)
  File "/home/richard/Electrum-3.3.5/electrum/daemon.py", line 58, in remove_lockfile
    os.unlink(lockfile)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/richard/.electrum/daemon'
```

Comment: It would have helped me if you had provided one of the links you found for x86_64, as I don't know what Electrum wallet is and may have seen issues you'll have with your different x86 architecture from your links.

Comment: i would check the ownership of files, that you didn't accidentally use `sudo` for a command (thus making `root` owner and denying yourself access), esp. /home/richard/.electrum/daemon

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sudo electrum` instead of `electrum` and it'll work.